# Android rear wide angle camera realtime streaming

Tags: video-streaming, google-pixel-6a

I plan to strap on my Pixel 6a on an RC car to do some low cost FPV driving. It works OK (except for moderate lag). However it would be much better if I was able to stream from backward facing wide angle camera. I am looking for an android app (native or browser - I don't care) but I wasn't able to find any that supports switching between multiple rear cameras. I tried Whatsapp, google meet, snapchat and some obscure ones. I even tried some browser apps, but they do not detect my wide angle camera. When I run https://browserleaks.com/webrtc the android system only "forwards" single front camera and single (main) rear camera.

I was worried that the wide angle camera was accessible only by native camera app, but no, Snapchat can use it too, but not during video conference. I found some internet guides that cycling between front and rear camera also cycles between wide and normal camera, but it doesn't work for my phone (pixel 6a).

Would anybody know how to solve this in a cleaner way than to glue wide angle camera lens on the main camera?

Comment: Have you tried OpenCamera or similar open source apps? If an open source app allows using the wide angle camera for videos then there is source code available that shows how to do it.